# QML How can I get current element index in ListView?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt5, qtquick2

As example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 250
    height: 250
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListModel {
            id: colorsModel
            ListElement { colorCode: "red"   }
            ListElement { colorCode: "green" }
            ListElement { colorCode: "blue"  }
            ListElement { colorCode: "orange"}
        }

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
            model: colorsModel

            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: 250
                height: 250
                color: colorCode
            }

            onMovementEnded: {
                console.log($CurrentElementIndex$)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get current element index to $CurrentElementIndex$ placeholder?

ListView.currentIndex is only write property, as if I understand correctly.

Maybe I can use ListView.indexAt(), but I don't understand how does it work.

Comment: What do you mean by write only variable?

Comment: console.log(currentIndex) always print "qml: 0". But "currentIndex = N" switched view in N item. (not "variable" -> "property", sorry)

Answer (score 2):

[`onMovementEnded()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5-snapshot/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#movementEnded-signal) is called when the list finished scrolling. That is independent of item selection. You could add a highlighter to debug which element is currently selected and use the `onCurrentIndexChanged` handler:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
    model: colorsModel

    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 250
        height: 250
        color: colorCode
    }

    highlight: Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "red"
    }

    onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log(currentIndex)

    // ...
```

Comment: No. I want it to get a new index during scrolling.

Comment: Then use `indexAt(3,3)` where you get the index of the element at position `x: 3px`, `y: 3px` from the top-left corner of the ListView. That should always be your first element during scrolling.

Comment: `onMovementEnded: console.log(view.indexAt(3, 3))` print `qml: 0 | qml: 0 | qml: 0 | qml: -1 | qml: -1 | ...`. But I want `qml: 0 | qml: 1 | qml: 2 | ...`

Comment: Maybe there's some way easier to get the desired outcome: if possible, just tell us which is your desired outcome. How do you want to use that index? I think that a `binding` over `contentY` combined with `indexAt` could work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `currentIndex` to get and set current selected item. 
But you said:

> I want it to get a new index during scrolling

so you need to set `highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange` in your ListView. This will change `currentIndex` property whenever you scrolled list.
Here is some example:

```
ListView {
    id: list
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: 10
    orientation: ListView.Vertical
    snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange     //<--This is the key note
    header: Component { Item { width: 1; height: 30 } }
    footer: Component { Item { width: 1; height: 30 } }
    preferredHighlightBegin: height/2-10    //<-----using these two lines you can control position of the selected item
    preferredHighlightEnd: height/2-10      //<--|
    currentIndex: 3
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        console.log("current selected index is: "+currentIndex);    //<-- Test output
    }

    delegate: Component {
        Text {
            id: _root
            width: parent.width
            height: 20
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            color: "#888"
            font { family: "Segoe UI Light"; pixelSize: 18 }
            text: index
        }
    }
}
```

For more info refer to documentations of Qt.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        model: colorsModel
        onCurrentIndexChanged {
        console.log("Index changed to "+currentIndex)
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 250
            height: 250
            color: colorCode  
            MouseArea {
              anchors.fill:parent
                onClicked{
                    list.currentIndex=index
                 }
            }
        }
```